# How to share api response throughout angular 2 application?

Tags: angularjs, angular2-template, angular2-services

I am calling REST API through service and using that service to get response in root component. So now I have api response(JSON object) in my root component and I want share that object in child component. How can I use that object in child component without calling service again?

In short, I don't want to call sever many times for same data (call api only once) and use that response throughout angular 2 application.

Could you please suggest how we can achieve this?

Comment: Better use localStorage. ex: localStorage.setItem('Your key',JSON.stringify(res.json()))

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using get and set.  Create a public variable with get and set.
Fisrt time when you get response simply set into that variable and after that call get method to retrieve same data.

```
public listData;

set listData(value){
this.listData =  value;
}

get listData(){
return this.listData;
 }
```

Comment: How can I access get and set in other component?

Comment: You can create a shared service file where you will declare these and in Component, you can import that shared service file.